# Array of struct pointers as first element of struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, tree

So I have a structure as follows:

```
typedef struct tree tree;

struct tree {
    tree* child[10];
    int value;
};
```

and a function to add a child and return its address as follows:

```
tree* tree_add_child(tree* parent, int index)
{
    tree* p = *(parent->child + index);

    if (p == NULL)
    {
          p = tree_new_tree(); //malloc new tree - init it - return its address
          *(parent->child + index) = p;
    }
    return p;
}
```

It works as I want it to as it is. But I'd like to replace all `parent->child`s with `parent`s since they point to the same address, and I feel like an extra memory access is not needed. But when I do that, I get an error that I'm trying to assign a `tree` to a `tree*`.

How could I do this, and are there any other optimizations that I could do to make this run faster?

Comment: The leading * is not necessary there because I would expect parent to already be a pointed.  You do not want to dereference its content, you want to point p to the address in parent + index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If understand the question, you want to replace

```
tree* p = *(parent->child + index);
```

with

```
tree* p = *(parent + index);
```

and likewise with the other instance of parent->child in order to optimize your program by reducing memory accesses.

There are no redundant memory accesses in the code as-is.

```
parent->child
```

and

```
parent
```

*do* have the same address, and the compiler knows this.  It doesn't have to look into memory to find out what the relative address of child is from parent.  It knows the offset (zero, in this case).  It's not like the structure contains a table of offsets for each of its members; they're known at compile time.  This is part of the reason that the full definition of a struct (and not just its name via forward declaration) must be known in order to use its members.

Even though this is the case, you can't just replace all expressions that happen to resolve to the same address with each other.  Type safety is there to protect you from making subtle mistakes of exactly that kind of replacement, and by ensuring you only assign "tree *" values to "tree *" variables (and so on), the compiler is helping you prevent errors.

Comment: Thanks. But just out of curiosity, if I wanted to do something like this, how would I go about it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  If you wanted to do something like what exactly?

Comment: @vitakraft You don't. parent and parent->child do not have the same type, and pointer arithmetic requires the correct type (since doing something like `+ child` moves `child` number of _objects_, not that number of _bytes_.

Answer (score 0):

I had this in a comment but it was too hard to properly format the text...

What you have now looks ok, but you don't really show what you tried to do.  For example, are you saying that you tried this:

```
tree *p = parent + index;
```

Is that what is returning the error?  If so, are you declaring parent to be a

```
struct tree parent;
```

or a

```
struct tree *parent;
```

You would need to declare it as the second.

Comment: `tree* p = *(parent + index);` sounded right to me but doesn't build. I also tried yours, it builds but doesn't work. I defined `parent` as a `tree*`, at the arguments.

Comment: At this point I'd suggest that you either do it by referencing the member or iterate over the structure using a void * and print out each value as a hex value.  You may have something happening in the compiler that is creating padding as the array or other values are being allocated.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
tree* p = parent + index;
```

Comment: That doesn't work, I don't need the pointer address, I need the object that the address points to.